# New to Python, need help where to put .lower() into my code

Tags: python

I am unsure where to put ".lower()" into my code below so the user can enter any of the three options without being case-sensitive. For example, they can enter NEW york and it wouldn't give an error because it's not spelled exactly as listed in the code.

```
while True:
      city = input ("\nWhich city would you like to filter by? New York, Chicago or Washington?\n")
      if city not in ('New York', 'Chicago', 'Washington'):
        print("Error, please choose from one of the options listed")
        continue
      else:
        break
```

Comment: There's no one place where you can put `.lower()` to fix your code. Have you read a good tutorial yet, aimed at programming beginners?

Comment: `if city.lower() not in ('new york', 'chicago', 'washington'):`

Comment: one way of making the check case sensitive is to map everything (the user input and the accepted answers to lowercase) before doing the comparisons.

Comment: @AndrasDeak--СлаваУкраїні: ? see Jespers comment

Comment: `city.title()` should work.

Comment: @ThomasWeller Jesper's comment changed the code elsewhere. I.e. as if they put `.lower()` in _two_ places.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to use the `lower()` method on a string like this `city.lower()`.  Although you'll get a further problem because your string will be lower case and your cities are title case which would need `city.title()` to match.

As long as you are consistent with your approach it will be fine as users will type anything from New York to NEW YORK to new york and EveERYThiNG between.

You can read more about the string methods [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#string-methods).

```
while True:
      city = input ("\nWhich city would you like to filter by? New York, Chicago or Washington?\n")
      if city.title() not in ('New York', 'Chicago', 'Washington'):
        print("Error, please choose from one of the options listed")
        continue
      else:
        break
```